# How to cut things using CSS or HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working on my website and I have made quite a progress with it. However as it is it's plain.
So I decided to make a few JavaScript animations that would bring my website to life.
However in JavaScript I only know to use specific resolutions given inside the canvas tag in html.

> ( Is it possible to do something like using percentages of the page
>   height and width like in css? )

So my JavaScript animation has a set resolution and I want to put it on my animation on a gradient rectangle on which I have some text.
So here is my problem. How can I put my animation on that rectangle without having to change the resolution on the canvas and without distorting the JS animation.

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


let position = {
x:0,
y:cvs.height/4
};

function resize() {
 // Our canvas must cover full height of screen
 // regardless of the resolution
 var height = window.innerHeight;
 
 // So we need to calculate the proper scaled width
 // that should work well with every resolution
 var ratio = cvs.width/cvs.height;
 var width = height * ratio;
 
 cvs.style.width = width+'px';
 cvs.style.height = height+'px';
}

window.addEventListener('load', resize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);

 ctx.fillStyle = "#66ccff";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);

function animation(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(position.x,position.y,10,30);
  position.x+=5;
  if(position.x>cvs.width){
  position.x = 0;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
animation();
```

```css
#group{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#5c85d6;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.some_text{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:1%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size:5vw;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
}

#myCanvas{
  position:absolute;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  top:-30%;
}

.some_other_text{
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  font-size:5vw;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhai', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="group">
    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "1000" height ="1500"></canvas>
    <h1 class = "some_text">Some text here</h1>
  </div>
  <h1 class = "some_other_text">Some more text that I want to see without the blue of my js animation</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes I could add a background to my second text that would cover the JavaScript animation so I can see only what I need however that would still render that covered part, slowing down the web-page loading time (I think).

Comment: I guess you can fix this without js but just with CSS transition

Comment: You can use percentages for width and height: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp
Also there is no need to think a loading time will be slowed down, just check it on the network tab of chrome dev tools. Pages may load slowly anyway b/c not all networks are created equal.